# Multidimensional Proof by Induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I have been given a recursive relation $$f(m,n)=f(m−1,n)+f(m,n−1)$$ in which I need to prove by mathematical induction that, $$f(m, n) = {(m + n)!\over(m!n!)}$$ over all natural numbers where
$$f(0, n) = 1,\ f(m,0) = 1,\text{and } m,n \gt 0$$

I have done induction before, but I'm having a hard time grasping how to solve this recursive equation with two variables. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I forgot to add where I got to. I have solved for the base cases where $m = 1$ and $n = 1$.
$$f(1,1) = f(1-1,1)+f(1,1-1) \\ f(1,1) = f(0,1)+f(1,0) \\ f(1,1) = 1+1 \\ f(1,1) = 2$$
which equals (I'm calling the other function $g$)
$$g(1,1) = {(1+1)!\over(1!1!)} \\ g(1,1) = {2\over1} \\ g(1,1) = 2$$

$$f(1,1) = g(1,1)$$

This all checks out, but this is where I am stuck, I'm not sure how to do the induction step with two variables.

Comment: It seems like a random pool of information. Why is it first $f$, then $g$, and what is $x,y$? Also, what is the recursive description of the function?

Comment: @String I'm sorry about that, I should've proof read it more before submitting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume (inferred from the OP) that we have the recursive relation
$$
f(m,n)=f(m-1,n)+f(m,n-1)
$$

---

Consider the following table for $f(m,n)$
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
(m,n)&0&1&2&3&...&n-1&n\\
\hline
0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&2&3&4&...&\vdots&\vdots\\
2&1&3&6&...&...&\vdots&\vdots\\
3&1&4&...&...&...&\vdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&1&...&...&...&...&\vdots&\vdots\\
m-1&1&...&...&...&...&\vdots&f(m-1,n)\\
m&1&...&...&...&...&f(m,n-1)&f(m,n)\\
\end{array}
$$
Suppose now that $f(m-1,n)=\frac{(m-1+n)!}{(m-1)!n!}$ and $f(m,n-1)=\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!(n-1)!}$. Then note that
$$
\begin{align}
f(m,n)&=f(m-1,n)+f(m,n-1)\\
&=\frac{(m-1+n)!}{(m-1)!n!}+\frac{(m+n-1)}{m!(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(m-1+n)!m+(m+n-1)!n}{m!n!}\\
&=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}
\end{align}
$$
and consider why this is enough to inductively fill the entire table ...

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful step-by-step answer with the table. I have edited my OP to include the recurrence equation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it goes like this:

1) Prove it's true for n=1 and all m.
2) Assume it's true for all k such that 1 <= k <= n, and for all m.
3) Now using 2) prove it's true for k=n+1 and for all m.

Comment: There's a name for it and I think it's Strong Induction.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas This is nested induction, not strong induction.